# Compile libcivil for ARM architecture

Tags: arm, webcam, raspberry-pi

i coded a java applications that takes the pictures of a webcam that is attached to the pc. For that i use the lti-civil java-api. It works fine! This api uses a shared library -libcivil.so- for jni access to several native libs. The libcivil.so exists for linux 32/64bit osx and windows. But i want the application to run with raspberry pi which has arm-architecture.

My question is: is it possible to recompile the libcivil - shared lib for arm-architecture? iam not familiar with c++ so i don't know if it is possible in any way.

Comment: I modified your question a bit to make it easier to understand (what I think is) your problem. Feel free to change anything back if I got it wrong.

Comment: you got everything right! thanks =]

Comment: Have you tried? The expectation is that clean code will compile. You may discover bugs on unportable bits that can be fixed by you or upstream.

Comment: no i haven't tried yet because i cannot find any sources.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to obtain webcam images with java on a raspberry pi. I use the v4l4j library. It's a jni wrapper for the v4l2 api. It handles direct access to the /dev/video interface under linux. There is a way to compile it for the raspbian linux-port and it works great. But the raspberry seems to be too slow (5-8 fps and hight latency - about 300-500ms). But this is another thing. Now iam waiting for the hackberry or gooseberry... =)

compile v4l4j on raspberry pi how-to:
https://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/wiki/GettingStartedOnRPi

greez
daniel